# Conditional existence of real numbers

Tags: number-theory

Are there such numbers $a$ and $b$ that if $a < b$, then $a > b$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: As TonyK points out, any $a$ and $b$ such that $a\not\lt b$ will do.  In such a case, $a\lt b$ will imply whatever you want.  Others interpreted it as meaning $a\lt b$ and $a\gt b$.  Could you please clarify?  (The title makes me think that you intended it as written, but given the potential misinterpretations I think clarification would help.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Take for instance a = 1, b = 0. (Or perhaps this isn't what you meant?)

Comment: Despite my answering in another sense, I disagree with the downvote.  This is a correct answer to the question as asked and may clarify the OP's intent.

Comment: um,I don't understand why $1 < 0 $ ?

Comment: I understand after reading Yasir Arsanukaev answer. +1 to both.

Comment: I am a big fan of first answering exactly the question that was asked and then seeing where things stand.  +1 for this.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The relation less than (as opposed to less than or equal to) is defined as strict, so $(a \lt b) \implies \neg (b \lt a)$

Comment: This answer would've been true, if I'd asked "Are there such numbers $a$ and $b$ that $a < b$ *and* $a > b$ ?" See my answer.

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev:  You are right, and I apologize for not reading it correctly.  I acknowledged that in my comment to TonyK's answer.

Comment: I just didn't notice you got the question correctly, it's possible because of my English :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't really think so. The condition $a < b$ implies that $a \ngeq b$ because $<$ is a total order on $\mathbb{R}$. If you're not familiar with orderings, they are just relations that are reflexive, anti-simmetric and transitive (see  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory). A set is said to be totally ordered if every element of the set can be compared to another with the ordering given.

Comment: It is not a well-ordering.  You mean to say that it is a strict total order.  The relation you defined with the modulus is not anti-symmetric, so it is not a partial order.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: you're right, I meant a total order, I'll correct and take off the example (dang, I thought it could be THAT easy...)